# Error Laravel 5.8 Eloquent - Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am working in Laravel 5.8 and struggling with a strange error.. I want to display Blog author name on blog detail page but it gives me error **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

**My Relation :**

> Blogs > Author

```
class Blog extends Model
{

    public function author_name(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class);
    }

}
```

**Admin Model**

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{

    public function blogs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Blog');
    }

}
```

**detail.blade.php**

```
{{ $blog->author_name->name }}
```

P.S : if I `dd($blog->author_name)` it gives correct id of author but when i call `->name object`. it gives above error

Comment: can you give this dd($blog->author_name)??

Comment: Check if belongsTo returns collection.

Comment: dd($blog->author_name) returns id of author

Comment: dd($blog->author_name) please put output of this code here or in question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add keys to relationships.

```
class Blog extends Model
{
public function author_name()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin','blog_id','blog_id'); //add your local key and foreign key here
}
}

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
public function blogs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Blog','blog_id','blog_id'); //add your local key and foreign key here
}
}
```

You can retrieve data by using

```
$blog = Blog::where('blog_id',1);
if(isset($blog->author_name))
  echo $blog->author_name->name;
```